# Matplotlib creates 30 page pdf but individual pages pulled in by latex seem to include most of big pdf

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib

This is a continuation of a question asked on the latex forum here which now appears to be a matplotlib issue. Here is the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207527/using-includegraphics-makes-pdf-very-large

This is the matplotlib code that created the pdf. This is where I set up the file for the pdf

```
pp = PdfPages(pdfName)
```

I then call the following code each time I want to create a new figure on a new page

```
font = {'family' : 'normal','weight' : 'normal','size'   : 18}
plt.rc('font', **font)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), dpi=100)

ax1 = plt.subplot(1,1,1)

ax1.set_xlabel(xLabel,fontdict={'fontsize':22})
ax1.set_ylabel(yLabel,fontdict={'fontsize':22})

ax1.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])

ax1.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])

numLines = len(cond1Values)

titleLabel = '$' + shortName2 + "=" + str(cond2Value) + '$'

ax1.set_title(titleLabel)
```

' I get 2 vectors of data called columnArray[0] and columnArray[1] which make the x and y axes  ' I also have a vector called errColumnArray[1] which containts the error bars

```
type= 'x-' #types[i]
```

' plot lines with error bars

```
plt.errorbar(columnArray[0],columnArray[1],yerr=errColumnArray[1], fmt='-', label=lineLabel)

plt.text(0.5, 0.9,titleLabel,
horizontalalignment='center',
fontsize=24, bbox={'facecolor':'black', 'alpha':0.02, 'pad':10},
transform = ax1.transAxes)

lg = ax1.legend()
lg.draw_frame(False)
lg.set_frame_on(False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.draw()

pp.savefig(fig)
plt.close()
```

This is then repeated for each of 30 figures to create the file. At the very end we call

pp.close()

The problem is that the resulting pages, each with a graph, cannot be pulled into latex without essentially pulling in something almost as big as the 30 page pdf.

I have discussed this with Andreas Matthias who wrote the includegraphics library in latex. He claims that there seem to be a lot of small PDF `objects' in the pdf file that seem to be common to all of the graphs and which are causing this bloat.

PS I would like to upload an example pdf but do not know how to.

Comment: Rather than saving all of the figures to a single pdf, why not save each figure to it's own pdf with `fig.savefig('file01.pdf')`, then in LaTeX use `\includegraphics{file01.pdf}`?

Comment: Because that would make about 400 files across all of my work. I thought this might simplify file management. I will do it if nothing else works.